# write a php array specific field to disk

Tags: php

I need to write ID #s from "cccr_mems,json" to a file "USCF_ID.txt" in php. I would really love to know how to do this. It would open up more possibilities for data exchange and manipulation.

the cccr_mems.json php array (~300 records)

```
[
{
"Name": "Adeyemon, Murie",
"Rating": 1000,
"CCCR_Exp": "1000.10.10",
"Class": "E",
"ID": 16720664
},
{
"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed",
"Rating": 1735,
"CCCR_Exp": "2018.10.18",
"Class": "B",
"ID": 12537964
}]



<?php //write IDs to file 
$lines = file('cccr_mems.json') or exit("Unable to open file!");

$myfile = fopen("USCF_ID.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach($lines as $x => $x_value) {

fwrite($lines.ID); //supposed to output $lines[ID]

fwrite "\n";

}

fclose($myfile);  

?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code you've got there?

Comment: This page isn’t working.

Comment: Not sure what `$lines.$x[ID]` is supposed to be.

Comment: @verlager, what isn't working? Are you having issues decoding the json, or looping through the array, or reading the file, or what?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I tried the code below and it doesn't write to the USCF_ID.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) plus [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) & [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
$json  = file_get_contents('cccr_mems.json'); // Reads entire file to string
$array = json_decode($json, true);            // Converts json to array

$id = [];
foreach($array as $value) {
    $id[] = $value['ID'];   // Get all ID
}

file_put_contents('USCF_ID.txt', explode(PHP_EOL, $id));  // Write string to file
```

Comment: I worked around it. np. Your code and suggestions were invaluable.